# OpenGL How fix direction draw circle/semi circle/arc from start to end point giving center, r start and end angle

Tags: c++, algorithm, opengl, trigonometry

How to draw circle or semi circle or arc from start(B) to end(C) point giving(without using **any** external library) in pure **C#** and **OpenGL** :

- A(Ax,Ay) - polyline
- B(Bx,By) - start point
- C(Cx,Cy) - end point
- M(Mx,My) - center of circle or semi circle or arc
- r - radius
- startAngle = atan2(B.y - M.y, B.x - M.x) - in radians
- endAngle = atan2f(C.y - M.y, C.x - M.x)  - in radians
- segments = 80

Unknow values:

- clockwise or anticlockwise direction

Requirements

- Arc must be drawing from point B to C

Can someone please provide me equation for drawing an arc in OpenGL?

**Hint:**

Will **it be a circle, a semicircle or arc it depends on the position** of the center of the circle and the start and end points.

Please give me a some light to solve this.

**-- EDIT --**

Below i present the solution. But it draw sometimes in wrong direction (should clockwise but it draw anticlockwise).:

[image]

```
float startAngle = atan2(B.y - centerArc.y, B.x - centerArc.x);
float endAngle = atan2(C.y - centerArc.y, C.x - centerArc.x);

if (endAngle < startAngle)
{
    endAngle += 2.0f * PI;
}

glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
for (float angle = startAngle; angle <= endAngle; angle = angle + 0.01f)
{
    float x = centerArc.x + cos(angle) * r;
    float y = centerArc.y + sin(angle) * r;
    glVertex2f(x, windowHeight - y);
}
glEnd();
```

It gives:
[image]

Comment: Haven't you asked the same question several times?

Comment: In Java or Android with ready libraries, yes.

Comment: Try to call  glDisable​(GL_CULL_FACE) before render. Maybe it is turned on by default.

Comment: "*Semi circle have to be bottom of the line and not on the top.*" Bottom relative to *what*? Lines do not have a "bottom" or a "top". So how do you determine which side of the line you want the arc drawn on?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your post please.

Answer (score 1):

The equation for points on a circle, semi-circle or circle arc is the same for all cases. The only variable that changes is the range in which the angle lies.

In pseudocode this looks as follows:

```
for angle in [startAngle, endAngle]
    p_on_circle = M + r * (cos(angle), sin(angle))
```

This assumes, that angle is given in radians, so one might want to just use

```
startAngle = atan2(B.y - M.y, B.x - M.x)
endAngle = atan2f(C.y - M.y, C.x - M.x)
```

**Edit**

Since atan2 produces angles in [-pi, pi] which makes some problems when `endAngle` is smaller than `startAngle` one has to make sure that the `endAngle` is always larger than the `startAngle`. This can, for example, be done by:

```
if (endAngle < startAngle)
    endAngle += 2*pi;
```

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you mean.

Comment: I see. The problem is, that the angles are in range from -pi to pi and you are not taking that into account. The easiest thing is to move add 2*pi to the angle when it is negative.

Comment: Exchanging B and C should do the trick. When B->C is the counter-clockwise part, then C->B will be the other direction.

Comment: how do you even know which orientation you want? Your problem is under-determined when not fixing the orientation. Unless you have any other constraint to determine the direction, I don't see any way how to do this. And it would make the world for both of us easier when you start with the full set of information on first place.

Comment: As already said: From the data you have, you will not be able to conclude which orientation is the right one. You could decide it depending on the line segment before the arc starts, but this would require at least on additional point.

Comment: Please remove this topic. Thx.